# ID conversion changes from Spring Data Rest Fowler to Gosling

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a service that is working fine using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and Spring Data Releastrain Fowler-SR2. When upgrading to Spring Data Releastetrain Gosling, my API breaks and I cannot figure out why.

If I have the following on my `Repository` interface:

```
public Page<Person> findByPerson(@Param("person")Person person, Pageable pagable)
```

And I call the endpoint with:

/service/people/search/findByPerson?person=100

SDR will correctly convert the id of 100 to the Person object (using the number as the PK id) and return the object. It will also work if I call it as:

```
/service/people/search/findByPerson?person=/service/people/100
```

When upgrading to the Gosling releasetrain, this all breaks. Now only the second version works, and any attempt to make the call using the numeric ids fails with an `org.springframework.data.repository.support.QueryMethodParameterConversionException` exception returned.

I cannot find any reference to this change in the Gosling release information, but I'm sure the change is related to going from Fowler to Gosling.

Anyone have any idea why this is, and how do I restore the functionality. This API is used in a lot of places, and having to update ALL clients is a BIG task. I want to take advantage of the security fixes and other improvements in the Gosling releastrain, and not be stuck on Fowler, but I cannot do that if I cannot restore this functionality, at least for some time to allow other clients to update their call methods.

Comment: Is this just part of the push to make SDR more RESTful? Did you get an answer anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got an answer, and it was "the old behavior was a bug, and what is happening now in Gosling is how it should always have worked. You must change your app(s) to match the behavior".

So I had to do quite a big change to our apps and clients to account for this.